# cartographic line develop spikes when applied offset value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, line

version: ArcGIS 10
I am using a number of lines in certain polygon. As I apply offset value to the outline, spikes/kinks are produced as shown in the picture. Any solutions to remove the spikes and represent line as it originally is? Plus why is there a greater distance between the lines at places then others, indicated in blue and pink lines.

[image]

Comment: I think you can solve your problem by Snap tool, Moves points or vertices to coincide exactly with the vertices, edges, or end points of other features. Snapping rules can be specified to control whether the input vertices are snapped to the nearest vertex, edge, or endpoint within a specified distance.

Comment: it is due to offset value and snapping comes in the least here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is an artefact of the cartographic line **endings** properties, joins and caps - Check out how the line caps are configured, and try different options out. You probably need bevelled joins and butt caps.
Apologies for not having a screenshot in English, but I though it might help you nonetheless.

The ESRI page on [Essential symbol and style vocabulary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s600000010000000) describes the behaviour of the different types of caps and joins.

[image]